# Form Validation when Input field is in HTML table and its type is "hidden"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have a working code to change the colors of table cells when clicked on a colored button and when the mouse is dragged on table cell all the cells involved in the drag gets that color, here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/28SMv/76/ ,

Now i want to do form validation like when the first table cell gets a color i want to echo out value and send it to database, i am not able to set the table cell values to the selected color, please help!

Comment: Please post some of your code - HTML form and PHP handler would be nice. Even some javascript would be cool!

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
$('our_table td').click(function(){
           $(this).css('background-color', selectedColor);
            alert($(this).children("input").val());
            $.ajax({
                    url: "add-product.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: $(this).children("input").val().serialize(),
                    error: function(data){
                        alert("There was an error while inserting into the database. );
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        Display_Load();
                        $("#content").load("pagination_data.php?page=1", function() {
                            Hide_Load()
                        });
                    }
                });
    });
```

It doesn't seem to be letting me do the alert in Fiddle, but once you can get the variable, just do an AJAX call to update a database somewhere.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: i have no idea about an AJAX call can you give me an example where this kind of thing is done

Comment: @user1586243:  You should read this jquery tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp, then read this ajax tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

Show line and column id and value to store in your database.

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28SMv/82/)**

To save data use:

```
var Params = { identificador: identificador, color : color };
$.ajax({
    url: 'pagetosave.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: Params,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('saved...');
    }
});
```

Replace it on each command.

Will be triggered once for each  ....

your php page will receive two parameters.... identificador e color.

Comment: I want to echo out the values, this works fine but instead of alert() is it possible to get the values echoed out, so that i can send the values to a database?

Comment: It would be nice to call a function via Ajax to save the data in the database.